# Accessing constraints/objective

Tags: pyomo

I'm using a toolbox that internally calls Pyomo to solve an optimization problem. I am interested in accessing the Pyomo model it constructs so I can modify the constraints/objective. So my question is, suppose I get the following output:

Problem:

Name: unknown
Lower bound: 6250.0
Upper bound: 6250.0
Number of objectives: 1
Number of constraints: 11
Number of variables: 8
Number of nonzeros: 17
Sense: minimize

Solver:

Status: ok
Termination condition: optimal
Statistics: 
    Branch and bound: 
    Number of bounded subproblems: 0
    Number of created subproblems: 0
Error rc: 0
Time: 0.015599727630615234

Solution:

number of solutions: 0
number of solutions displayed: 0

So the problem works well and I get a solution, the modeling was done internally via another too. Is it possible to access the constraints/objective so I can freely modify the optimization model in Pyomo syntax?

I tried to call the model and got something like this: 
`<pyomo.core.base.PyomoModel.ConcreteModel at xxxxxxx>`

Comment: Include a code sample showing what you've tried so far and the full error message it generates.

Comment: I do not have an error message. I am trying to figure out how to access the model information and modify its constraints. Right now all I know is it is called 'network.model' and it is concrete. I did not construct the model, but I want to access it fully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like `network.model` is the Pyomo model and yes, if you have access to it, you can modify it. Try printing the model or individual model components using the `pprint()` method:

```
network.model.pprint()
network.model.con1.pprint()
```

or you can loop over specific types of components in the model:

```
for c in network.model.component_objects(Constraint):
    print(c)  # Prints the name of every constraint on the model
```

The easiest way to modify the objective would be to find the existing one, deactivate it, and add a new one

```
network.model.obj.deactivate()
network.model.new_obj = Objective(expr=network.model.x**2)
```

There are ways to modify constraints/objectives in place but they are not well-documented. I'd recommend using Python's `dir()` function and playing around with some of the component attributes and methods to get a feel for how they work.

```
dir(network.model.obj)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. I am able to re-define simple constraints/objective. Now,
I ran 'network.model.con1.pprint()' to see the constraint 'con1' and got the following: 

con1: Size=2, Index=c1, Active=True
    Key: Lower: Body: Upper : Active
    ('gen 0', 'now') :   0.0 : 100.0*gen_status[gen 0,now] - gen_p[gen 0,now] :  +Inf :   True
    ('gen 1', 'now') :   0.0 : 50*gen_status[gen 1,now] - gen_p[gen 1,now] :  +Inf :   True

This is an indexed constraint. How can alter the first element? Let's say I only want to replace 100 with 25, without messing up with everything else?

Comment: Access a single index of an indexed components using square brackets `network.model.con1['gen 0','now']. The easiest way to change the value would be to modify the original Constraint rule to use a mutable Param in place of the numeric constant 100.0. Then you could change the value without directly modifying the constraint.

Comment: Thanks, Bethany. I cannot modify the original constraint because it came out of some other tool and unfortunately they did not use Param. I guess I'll build everything myself and use Pyomo directly. I love it so far! Big thanks to dev team.